# Title capitalization of hyphenated words

Tags: style, hyphens, capitalization

I always see the following titles differently and I want to know about what is the proper capitalization of title words when joined by a hyphen (dash):

> Object-[**o**]riented Programming
>
> ***or***
>
> Object-[**O**]riented Programming

Should I capitalize the 'O' after using a dash? or does this only depend on the way of writing?

I would go for the first one if you asked me :)

Comment: If you want to capitalize the P, I think it should be "Object-Oriented Programming", otherwise OOP would be a strange term.

Comment: I came _this close_ to retitling this question "Title Capitalization of Hyphen-Separated Words".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be...

> Object-Oriented Programming

*The Gregg Reference Manual* suggests that in a heading or title, capitalize all the elements except articles, short prepositions, and short conjunctions.

Here, the word *oriented* is an adjective and thus takes capitalization.

[Good read on Business Writing here.](http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2010/08/capitalizing-hyphenated-words-in-titles-.html)  Good question though :)

Interesting comparison is [here](http://www.accu-assist.com/grammar-tips-archive/GrammarTip_capitalization-titles-headings-hyphenated-words.htm).

[image: Source: accu-assist]

Answer (score 0):

Capitalize them both.

> Object-[**O**]riented Programming

Comment: Based on...? It would be nice if you cited something authoritative to support your answer. Otherwise, perhaps it should just be a comment.